# Exception-safe logging in java

Tags: java, logging, exception-safety, exception-safe

I have a (probably) weird question about logging in an exception-safe way in java.

Let's say I have this code in java:

```java
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
{
    log.debug(...expression...);
}
```

Is there a best practice for logging `...expression..` in a way that any exception during evaluation doesn't make my application fail?

For example, I'd like this code to not break my application:

```java
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
{
    log.debug("a divided by b is " + (a/b)); // throws an exception if b is zero
}
```

I can obviously write my own wrapper that uses a lambda function *(something like wrapperLog.debug(()->"a divided by b is " + (a/b));* but I'd like to know if there is a best practice for these kind of situations.

Comment: There is pretty much no such thing as "best practice". People have different opinions about things, especially programmers.

Answer (score 3):

To be safe don't log expressions or the result of a method call.  Log plain variables only: primitive types or bean types with a `toString()` generated by your IDE; in the latter case don't call `toString()` explicitly.

Comment: I was about to write the same. I think logging generally should be simple enough that there should be no need for exception handling.

Comment: Unfortunately, on the projects I work on, this approach is not feasible: there already is a lot of suboptimal code and management mandate the preference. of fast development over quality one, so "doing things the right way" is not a policy I can enforce.<br/><br/>

Also, even if I were able to, I wouln't be able to enforce that policy in the future, when other (usually less experienced people) will take over the code<br/><br/>
So my problem is not "how to do logging correctly" (that is out of the question).
My problem is "how to do logging without the logging breaking the application".

Comment: So the question is: "I know that my code is poor, how can I make it exception-safe without changing it?".  Sorry, no solution.